# Memory could not be written when using Adobe 10.0 reader

Tags: windows-xp, memory, pdf

User using is attempting to read a PDF file from a web server and gets the following error

Message:

> Report[1].pdf (SECURED) - Adobe Reader: Acrord32.exe Application Error:  The instruction at '0X00000119' reference memory at 0x0000119. the memory could not be written.

User is using XP, Adobe 10.0 reader.

How can I resolve this error and read the pdf document?

Comment: all PDF or just from one web server. Is it *your* web server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a KB article adressing Adobe Reader crashes/memory issues:

[Errors and freezes -- Adobe Reader -- Windows](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/333/333626.html)

> Different factors can cause system errors, including conflicts among device drivers, software, and hardware, and corrupt elements in specific files. Although a system error may occur only when you work with Adobe Reader, Adobe Reader may not necessarily be the cause--it may be the only application that is memory- or processor-intensive enough to expose the problem.